# Come on, don’t be such a nimrod!

Tags: etymology, slang, proper-nouns, historical-change, hebrew

According to the OED, the word English ***Nimrod*** is derived from the Hebrew, where in Genesis 10:8–9 he is described as ‘a mighty one in the earth’ and ‘a mighty hunter before the Lord’.  It is apparently still [a popular name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimrod_Kamer) in Israel.

This would match the OED’s definitions:

> 1. A tyrannical ruler; a tyrant. *Obs*.
> 2. A great hunter; one who is fond of, or given to, hunting.

But you never hear it used that way any longer. Now it’s become some sort of slang that means something more like dunce or idiot or jerk.

While I doubt that PETA was involved, I still would like to know what the exact history is that lies behind this new anti-hunter motif?

Comment: http://leanleft.com/2004/02/23/the-etymology-of-nimrod/ "probably from the phrase poor little Nimrod, used by the cartoon character Bugs Bunny to mock the hapless hunter Elmer Fudd"

Comment: @MετάEd “Probably” isn’t very strong. There should be some way to plot this on a graph.

Comment: The *OED*'s first citation for *nimrod* in this sense is from 1933, but the first appearance of Bugs Bunny was in 1937 or so (depending on what you count).

Comment: @GarethRees Can you share the citation?

Comment: "1933   B. Hecht & G. Fowler *Great Magoo* iii. i. 183   He's in love with her. That makes about the tenth. The same old Nimrod. Won't let her alone for a second." This suggestions the evolution of senses was *skilful hunter* → *hunter* → *failed hunter* → *idiot*.

Comment: Not to get into a deep discussion of epistemology, but every assertion one makes is at best "probably true", with varying degrees of certain. I can't say with 100% certainty that tchrist exists: maybe it's just a fake name created by another user on here to hide his excessive number of posts. I can't say with 100% certainly that France exists: I've never been there, nor have I ever met anyone who claims to have been there. Maybe it's a fictional place invented by the British to frighten small children. Etc.

Comment: The practice of nicknaming someone in an ironic fashion is much older than this citation. Hecht/Fowler are doing it; Bugs is doing it. Perhaps the interesting question is when did "nimrod" take on a life of its own, independent of the Biblical meaning?

Comment: I agree with MετάEd:  I suspect common usage came with Bugs Bunny.  Plus, it sounds a little like "numbskull" or the like.  Where I'm from it's also common to call someone a "dilrod", which is morphed a step further.  IMHO the 1933 citation is in the hunter sense:  He's a "hunter" of women, and won't leave this one alone..."

Comment: Surely some of these should be Answers not just ephemera!

Comment: I'm not convinced there's any "anti-hunter" sentiment in the (limited) currency of forms like [Don't be such a nimrod!](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22be+such+a+nimrod%22&oq=%22be+such+a+nimrod%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.669976j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). More likely just people conflating two relatively unfamiliar words - ***nimrod/nincompoop***.

Comment: I've always assumed the pejorative sense was related to the penis connotations. I doubt it has anything to do with hunting, but rather the word itself: the diminutive-sounding "nim-" paired with the phallic term "rod". Compare *dipstick*—the thing we use to check our oil is useful and generally competent to its job, and yet the word has become slang for "a stupid or inept person" as well as the part of the male anatomy most likely to be compared to a stick. I don't have any hard evidence to back that guess up, though.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this might be mostly an American phenomenon. I had a professor of British origin who only knew of Nimrod in its classical sense so didn't understand why I found this case a case of nominative determinism: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_Royal_Air_Force_Nimrod_crash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OED online has a wider second definition than that given in the question:

> 2. A great or skilful hunter (freq. *ironic*); any person who likes to hunt. Also *fig*.

This "frequently ironic" may be the transitional clue between the great hunter of old and the stupid or contemptible person of today, first quoted by the OED in 1933.

The 2008 *New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English* says:

> **nimrod** *noun* a fool, a stupid person, a bungler. Jonathan Lighter writes that ‘currency of the term owes much to its appearance in a 1940s Warner Bros. cartoon in which Bugs Bunny refers to the hunter Elmer Fudd as "poor little Nimrod"’. It is not clear that watchers of the cartoon understood the C18 sense of the word as ‘a great hunter’, but the term has stuck *US, 1932*

The OED's 1933 is somewhat ambiguous, it could be referring to a bad hunter:

> 1933   B. Hecht & G. Fowler *Great Magoo* iii. i. 183   He's in love with her. That makes about the tenth. The same old Nimrod. Won't let her alone for a second.

Their next idiot quotation isn't until 1963. However, [etymonline.com](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Nimrod&allowed_in_frame=0) isn't convinced by Bugs Bunny changing the meaning:

> It came to mean "geek, klutz" by 1983 in teenager slang, for unknown reasons. (Amateur theories include its occasional use in "Bugs Bunny" cartoon episodes featuring rabbit-hunting Elmer Fudd as a foil; its possible ironic use, among hunters, for a clumsy member of their fraternity; or a stereotype of deer hunters by the non-hunting population in the U.S.)

---

As it happens, *Nimrod* is also given as one amongst two whole-column-lengths of synonyms for *penis* in Farmer and Henley's 1891 *[Slang and its analogues past and present](https://www.archive.org/stream/slangitsanalogue02farmuoft#page/209/mode/1up)*.

The [1902 edition](https://archive.org/stream/slanganditsanal00henlgoog#page/n27/mode/1up) defines it:

> **NIMROD**, *subs*, (colloquial). — I. A 
>   hunting-man ; a sportsman.
>
> 1. *subs*, (venery). — The *penis*. 
>      [Because 'a mighty hunter']. *See* 
>      CREAMSTICK and PRICK.

Perhaps not relevant, but from the same volume:

> **NIMENOG**, *subs*. (old). — A fool. Also 
>   NIGMENOG.—B. E. (1696).

Comment: "It is not clear that watchers of the cartoon understood the C18 sense of the word as ‘a great hunter’". This understated comment nails it. The word took on a life of its own when it was heard and adopted by hundreds of thousands of children who heard it over and over without any idea that it was ironic.

Comment: And just which sort of *venery* might that be referring to, the one related to venison or the one related to Venus — or both? :)

Answer (score 3):

Nimrod, in the Old Testament of the Bible, was the great-grandson of Noah and the 1st King of Babylon who built the Tower of Babel. He was known as a great hunter.

The name morphed in the 19th century when Charles Apperley wrote *[The Life of a Sportsman](https://archive.org/details/lifeofsportsman03nimr)* in England, using the pen name Nimrod. He was a poor fox hunter who kept falling off his horse into "the drink," and the name *Nimrod* came to be known as a klutz.

Comment: It would be great if you would add some quotes or references.

Answer (score 1):

I can add that Nimrod was understood by high school students in Southern California as meaning "idiot" by 1963, when I learned the word only with that meaning.

Comment: Can you back up your answer with evidence?

Comment: Maybe the answer was not well-suited for this arena; however, am I the only one who thinks it ridiculous to ask one to provide evidence for his personal experience?

Comment: I can attest that I also heard the term during the 60s (in Kentucky) with the same sense.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the source of the "idiot" definition for nimrod is the small town of Nimrod in Minnesota.  It had a state run insane asylum.  Locals in the area use to call people that were acting crazy nimrods.

Comment: That would be the First State Asylum for the Insane, later renamed to Anoka State Hospital.  Do you have a reference for the rest of that?

Comment: If this is referring to Anoka State Hospital, this would seem unlikely, since Anoka is 150 miles away from Nimrod.

Also, Nimrod was founded in 1946, 8 years after Daffy Duck (not Bugs Bunny) used the term for Elmer Fudd in "What Makes Daffy Duck".

Answer (score 0):

You are ALL wrong...Nimrod was the world's first "Anti-Christ" figure. He appeared not long after the flood when the sons of Noah's sons had "multiplied upon the earth"-Genisis. God instructed the post flood humans to "spread out upon the face of the Earth" But Nimrod, who had conquered most peoples in existence at the time, did NOT want to divide his kingdom.

So he devised a plan to "deal" with God. Build a tower up to heaven, enter God's throne room and kill him.

The Tower was built (at least 95% of it was) God came down and said "THIS they devise to do...and now nothing they imagine will be restrained from them, come, let us confound their languages, so they may not understand one another"

After this, Nimrod was foiled. Standing near the peak of his tower and watching his former subjects "babel" at one another, he knew he could not win...so he turned, looked up, and "SHOOK HIS FIST AT GOD"

It is for that last action that "Don't be a Nimrod" came to mean, "Don't be an idiot" For only an Idiot shakes his fist at God.

2/3's of the Tower of Babel was destroyed, but 1/3 still stands. It is Mt Kalish in Tibet.

Comment: Donal Finn, no matter what merits your answer might have, they need to be supported with more than suggestion  as to where that support may be. It would be best to cite chapter and verse,and, spell words as they are in dictionaries; you will have a more positive experience if you do.

Comment: @J. Taylor Thank you for being the first to respond. I've been accused of using sarcasm in responses, but believe I've stopped at the irony level. But I came very close here. / Perhaps the obvious mistakes should have not been pointed out, so that readers could have some benchmark by which to begin to appraise the above unsupported claim. / The 1933 'Great Magoo' mention, which seems the first attested for the 'dope/ass' sense, is 'failed hunter' related. I'm used to the 'mighty hunter (evil; of people ... conqueror / enslaver' flavour for 'Nimrod' from Elgar and Bible studies. Not the 'ass'.